# Xamarin.Forms, Binding to a method

Tags: mvvm, xamarin

is it possible to bind to a method instead of property in Xamarin Forms, similar to `{Binding GetImage()}`, I have to download encrypted images those are in encrypted string format from web server and display those images on listview, for that i have to use the async and await operators, but with property, i cannot use those operators.

Comment: You can always call async methods synchronously, so using properties is never a problem.

Comment: If your context implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you should be able to raise a PropertyChanged event when your image finishes downloading.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li for the info, i was able to call an async method with in a getter, but the application hangs, even if binding to a method is possible, i suspect it will hang, i should find out some other way to download the image without having any performance issue.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I am now trying to implement using INotifyPropertyChanged, but i don't want to download all the image at once, there will be more than 100 images, i think i should try downloading the image lazily.

Comment: You don't have to download them all at once - it might help if we knew more about what you were doing.  Presumably you are binding to a collection, and each item in the collection has an image property.  So each item would implement INPC, and fire the PropertyChanged event when it's image was downloaded.

Comment: Hi Jason, I have to bind to a collection, but the image URL does not contains link to an image, but that image URL calls a Restful Get Web service, that returns image in base64 string after encryption. I have to decrypt the string and change the base64 to ImageSource and call the NotifyPropertyChanged method.